# Blogger show external image thumbnail in popular posts

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

There is a `Popular Post Widget` provided by Blogger, which can find the popular posts' first image and show it on the sidebar of your blog.

But it can only find images which are directly uploaded to Blogger, it doesn't work on external image links. I'm wondering if there's a way to read the external image by editing its code, maybe in javascript I think...

The default generated code:

```
<!-- (3) Show only thumbnails or (4) Snippets and thumbnails. -->
<div expr:class='data:showSnippets ? &quot;item-content&quot; : &quot;item-thumbnail-only&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable or data:post.thumbnail'>
        <div class='item-thumbnail'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.href' target='_blank'>
                <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable ? resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 72, &quot;1:1&quot;) : data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
                    <img alt='' border='0' expr:src='data:image'/>
                </b:with>
            </a>
        </div>
    </b:if>
    <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>
    <b:if cond='data:showSnippets'>
        <div class='item-snippet'><data:post.snippet/></div>
    </b:if>
</div>
```

Since there are so many `b:if` and `data:` in the code, I'm not sure if I can treat it as a normal `html` file or not.

Comment: Now the `<data:post.featuredImage/>` data tag is able to get the external images and no change in the code is required.

Comment: @PrayagVerma I have following code in my template. But it doesn't seem to work. I have an external image in the post.
<b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable ? resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 72, &quot;1:1&quot;) : data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
<img alt='' border='0' expr:src='data:image'/>
</b:with>

Can you ellaborate how it worked for you.

Comment: @LazyCoder Could you share the URL of the blog where you are experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a widget below, which can show popular posts' thumbnail by external images. Copy all the code and add it as a widget fixes the problem.

It gets the first image in the posts, both internal images and external images worked well.

Code: [GitHub](https://github.com/j3soon/Blogger-Widgets/blob/master/PopularPostsWidget.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
<!-- (3) Show only thumbnails or (4) Snippets and thumbnails. -->
<div expr:class='data:showSnippets ? &quot;item-content&quot; : &quot;item-thumbnail-only&quot;'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable or data:post.thumbnail'>
              <div class='item-thumbnail'>
                <a expr:href='data:post.href'>
                  <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable?resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 65, &quot;65:52&quot;): data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
                    <img class='featuredImage' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:image' height='52' layout='responsive' width='65'/>
                  </b:with>
                </a>
              </div>
            </b:if>
            <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>
            <b:if cond='data:showSnippets'>
              <div class='item-snippet'><data:post.snippet/></div>
            </b:if>
          </div>
```